# Confusion over uniqueness property of ring of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

I'm just learning about the ring of fractions of a ring $R$. Take the following definition

> Let $D \subset R$ be a non-empty subset of a commutative ring $R$ with
>   the properties that $0 \notin D$, there are no zero-divisors in $D$
>   and $D$ is closed under the multiplication in $R$. Then there is a
>   unital commutative ring $Q$ such that $R$ is a subring of $Q$ and
>   every element of $D$ is a unit in $Q$.

There are two additional properties; the first says that every element of $Q$ is of the form $rd^{-1}$ for some $r \in R$ and $d \in D$. This is clear to me.

The second property says that $Q$ is the unique smallest ring containing $R$ that turns all elements of $D$ into units.

The proof goes as follows, sparing some details;

Let $\iota : R \to Q$ with $\iota(r) = \frac{rd}{d}$ for some $d \in D$ (not that $d$ is non-zero and not a zero divisor). I have shown that $\iota$ is a ring monomorphism, so that $R$ embeds into $Q$ (and $r$ can be identified with $ \iota(r)$ in $Q$). 
Suppose now that $S$ is any commutative ring and $\varphi : R \to S$ is a ring monomorphism such that $\varphi(d)$ is a unit in $S$ for all $d \in D$. Extend $\varphi$ to the map $\Phi : Q \to S$ by defining $\Phi(rd^{-1}) = \varphi(r)\varphi(d)^{-1}$ for all $r\in R$, $d \in D$. Then $\Phi$ is a ring homomorphism (I've checked this) and $\Phi$ is injective, since $rd^{-1} \in \ker \Phi$ implies that $\varphi(r)\varphi(d)^{-1} = 0$, which implies that $\varphi(r) = 0$, and since $\varphi$ is a monomorphism, this forces $r = 0$, so that $\ker \Phi = \ker \varphi = \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$. **Hence $Q$ is unique**.

I'm confused about the conclusion in bold. How does this prove that $Q$ is unique?

Edit: It seems that the composition $\Phi \circ \iota = \varphi$, which looks distinctly like a universal property.

Comment: This construction seems like a generalization of the construction of a field of fractions to an integral domain. You have found that $Q$ is unique in the sense that if $S$ is any other commutative ring in which the elements $\varphi (d)$ are units there is always an injective homomorphism from $Q \to S$. In this way $Q$ is $\textbf{the}$ smallest commutative ring in which the elements of $D$ are units. This argument is possible because of the existence of $\Phi$. I left this as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not sure if this is fully fleshed out.

Comment: I think $Q$ is only unique *up to unique isomorphism*.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Yes this seems to be the case. Does the definition mean that any ring containing copies of $R$ AND $D^{-1}$ must also contain a copy of $Q$?

Comment: The usual statements are: (a) There is a ring $Q$ and a morphism $f:R\to Q$ such that, $f(d)$ is invertible for all $d\in D$, and for all morphism $g:R\to S$ such that $g(d)$ is invertible for all $d\in D$ there is a morphism $h:Q\to S$ such that $h\circ f=g$. (b) If $f':R'\to Q'$ has the same property, then the unique morphism $Q\to Q'$ given by (a) is an isomorphism. The proof is almost obvious.

Comment: You can look at $D = \langle a \rangle$ and how $R$ embeds in $R[a^{-1}]$